# Confusion about the use of back to back square brackets in Python

Tags: python, syntax

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to follow a YouTube tutorial about how to create a Connect Four game. In the code there are numerous times where square brackets are used back to back, and I'm confused about what these are doing. Here's an example:

`board[row][col] == piece`

Here's the code I have thus far for more context:

```
import numpy as np

ROW_COUNT = 6
COLUMN_COUNT = 7

def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((6,7))
    return board

def drop_piece(board, row, col, piece):
    board[row][col] == piece
    

def is_valid_location(board, col):
    return board[5][col] == 0

def get_next_open_row(board, col):
    for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
        if board[r][col] == 0:
            return r

board = create_board()
print(board)
game_over = False
turn = 0

while not game_over:
    #Ask for Player 1 Input
    if turn == 0:
        col = int(input("Player 1 make your move (0-6)."))
        
    #Ask for Player 2 Input
    else:
        col = int(input("Player 2 make your move (0-6)."))

    turn += 1
    turn = turn % 2
```

Since the question I have involves functions and not just straight variables, I was unsure how to test the functionality of the back to back brackets.

Comment: `board[row][col]` This is, most likely, a list-of-lists.  So `board` is a list, and `board[row]` is a sub-list inside the main list.

Comment: @JohnGordon you might think so, but you can see in `create_board` that it's a 2D numpy array.

Comment: @MarkRansom I might have known that, if I knew anything about numpy.

Comment: Why are you using numpy for this? As a beginner you should familiarise yourself with Python basics (lists in this case) before delving into the mysteries of numpy

Answer (score 0):

This is related to 2D array.

For example:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(arr[0])
print(arr[1])
print(arr[0][0])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
1
```

So, I think here: `board[row][col] == piece`
You try to find the 2D array of "board" and make sure it equals to "piece"

Here [an interesting article](https://www.scaler.com/topics/2d-array-in-python/) about 2D array in Python:

> In a 2D array, multiple arrays are inserted as elements in an outer
> array. Each element in a 2D array is represented by two indices, the
> row and the column. 2D arrays in python are zero-indexed, which means
> counting indices start from zero rather than one; thus, zero is the
> first index in an array in python.

Comment: To be precise, there are no 2D arrays in Python. That's a list containing other lists (which can be used to represent 2D arrays).

Comment: The article is quite misleading in the way it describes memory management. As said, this "2D array" is actually a list of lists: there's no guarantee that the whole structure is contiguous in memory like the article presents it as. Also, it makes statements which are just flat-out wrong like *"We can create a 2D array in python as below: `array_name=[n_rows][n_columns]` "*